How to size heatsink for this thermoelectric cooling application
I want the cold side of this TEC(Peltier module) to be held at 0°C and need to size a heatsink. For my setup, I only plan to tape a small wire element to the cold side, along with a thermistor for feedback to a TEC controller, and nothing else. But to the hot side I have to attach a big enough heatsink otherwise hot side will cumulate heat and things won't work.
The problem is that the parameter called "ΔT" is in the core of estimations and charts of a TEC. And to calculate "ΔT", one must know the temperature at the cold side and at the hot side. One can say a TEC controller will regulate the cold side to 0°C so we can say "okay I know the temperature for the cold side". But then I'm stuck. When steady state is reached I have no idea what will the hot side's temperature be. So it means, at this very early stage I didn't even come to a point to size a heatsink.
So in my case, the estimation of hot side is unknown to me and I'm totally lost at this point to proceed to look for a proper heatsink. I cannot find any step by step procedure. And a step by step clear explanation with rough estimate would be great.

As you lower the ΔT, the cooling becomes more efficient, or should I say, less horribly inefficient. Although the 12706 claims a max ΔT of 60 C and more, the heat transport Q is zero there. You need a ΔT nearer to 20 C, certainly below 30 C if you want any reasonable performance.
You therefore want the hot side to be as cool as possible within your space or money budget. Use the biggest heatsink you can fit or afford. A waterblock would be the best hotside heatsink, ideally running chilled water.
The most straightforward way to calculate the temperature rises is to use the  graphs furnished in the datasheet you linked.
You know your required cooling Q from your experimental setup. You have defined the cold side to be at 0 C, you know how much heat your experiment is producing, and how much heat leak from ambient to cold side will get through your cold side enclosure. I'm going to assume 15 watts for subsequent working.
The datasheet has graphs for hot side of both 25 C and 50 C. The former is appropriate for a well-cooled water block, the latter for an air-cooled heatsink with a reasonable rise over ambient.
For the ΔTs of 25 C and 50 C, see what current you need for that Q. For 15 W Q, you need about 3 A for 25 C hotside, and about 4.5 A for 50 C hotside. The dissipated power will be 3x3x2 = 18 watts and 4.5x4.5x2.3 = 47 watts respectively. Add the 15 watts Q, and your heatsink will need to dissipate either 33 watts at 25 C or 62 watts at 50 C.
You will need to make some measurements to verify this performance, and whether the device actually performs as the data sheet promises. I suggest you do these measurements earlier, rather than later. I have always learned something I didn't expect to learn when doing an experiment. Glue a small resistor to the cold side as a heat source for Q, and with a big hotside heatsink, run the peltier at very low power, and plot the Q vs ΔT for yourself. Repeat at different powers and Qs.
Operation tip. You MUST run your peltier from smooth DC, chopping/PWMing is not a good idea. If you are going to control the coldside temperature by varying the cooling power, then use a filtered output SMPS converter to do the control (or a linear), but not PWM. The heat pumped through the device is linearly proportional to current. The heat generated within the device is proportional to current squared. Unfiltered PWM increases the RMS heating power, and reduces further the already horrible efficiency.

I still do not understand and dont know how to progress. You say estimate Q and find ΔT. To estimate Q I need to know or estimate ΔT. Its like chicken or egg question. There are two unknowns here for me both ΔT and Q are unknown and I dont know how to estimate them in my case. I can see its a difficult thing anyways from no comments and single answer without any concrete solution...

@user16307 updated my answer with sample calculations. You could of course derive some equations from the graphs in the data sheet, and invert them so you get a synthesis, but for something like this, repeated analysis to arrive at an outline for a design is just as appropriate.

Im sorry to dig it but would be glad if you could address these three: 1-) How did you come up with 4.5 A for 50 C hotside? Isn't the intersection point of Q 15W and ΔT 25C is at between current lines of 1.5A and 3A? 2) How did you estimate 15W at the beginning? Is that about my setup with tape and wire? 3-) One thing confuses me using the chart and meaning of it. Lets say I use the hot side graph 50C. Doesn't it mean graph is valid for hot side for only 50C. already But your example you took ΔT as 25C. That makes the hot side 25C for 0C cold side. This is a bit confusing.

@user16307 1) if you want coldside=0 and hotside=50, then dT is 50, not 25, so the solution is the 4.5 A line. 2) Q=0 assumes perfect thermal insulation to the coldside, which isn't going to happen. Even if you have perfect insulation, and your test piece generates no heat, you will still want to cool it down at a reasonable rate. I had originally started working with a guess of 10 W for Q, but 15 W lands on the lines of the graphs! It's well below the Qmax for the part. If you have a definite figure for Q, then use that. 3) see next comment.

@user16307 3) as you want a coldside = 0C, I used dT=25 with the Th=25 graphs on the left, and dT=50 for the Th=50 graphs on the right. I think that's where you got confused at point 1. This difference between the graphs, and THEN the difference between the dTs, is what makes a high dT so bad for efficiency, and why I recommended at para 1 in my first reply to get the hot side as cool as possible, as cool as you can afford.

I see but I think at dT=50 for Q=15W the points intersect the 3A line. Could u recheck it? And I really appreciate you answer, it is hard to find some feedback from who has experience with this. Do you mind I open a new question? (In this case, if the Peltier used as heating from ambient t and to keep the hot side at 50C. Where the hot side will be where I want to regulate and tape the wire and thermistor and heatsink will be on cold side.)

I see you used Th=25C graph so seems dT=50 for Q=15W the points intersect the 3A line(I use Th=50 graph because I plan to use non-water cooled heatsink).

Oh sorry about the intersection. I think Im getting stupid. Yes for 50C graph it is 4.5A.

I know opened a new question, hope you can also write to that: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/732847/how-to-size-heatsink-for-this-thermoelectric-heating-application

You're correct that sizing a heatsink for a Peltier module involves some circular dependencies, as the hot-side temperature influences the heat dissipation, which in turn influences the temperature gradient (\$ΔT\$) across the TEC. You want the cold side at 0°C=273°K and assuming the ambient is 25°C to have better cooling you want the hot side > 25°C for forced-air cooling or else, add a water-cooled 2ndary heat pump.
Let's assume a forced-air solution with some suitable CPU cooler and let \$ΔT=40°C\$ for an initial estimate.
Assume \$Q_h≈P_{input}\$
compute Rth {sink to ambient} \$R_{sa}\$   with case=cooler temp, \$T_c\$ assuming silver thermal grease on a clean coplanar interface and add margin later.
\$R_{sa}=\frac{(T_c+ΔT)−T_{ambient}}{I⋅V}=\frac{15_{40-25}}{Vin*Iin} [°C/W]\$
A decent CPU heatsink is 0.1 °C/W (to 0.12) so a practical limit will be < 100W to the Peltier array.  Your cooler at 40C is 15.4 Vmax * 6.4 Amax = 99 W.  So you want a good CPU heatsink/fan perhaps from a surplus old PC.
Then attach a thermistor to the heatsink case or target device to regulate the fan speed for 0°C. In the thermistor bridge, include some partial derivative RC feedback filtering to anticipate the change due to the thermal latency of a few seconds with a high-air velocity fan improving the convection cooling Rth and time constant by a factor of 10 or more.  The thermistor may be glued with a dab of epoxy taped tight or clamped and magnet wire twisted-pair feedback to a connector, if desirable.  Fan speed control can be an LM317 with an NPN feedback bias control or an Op Amp to drive an Nch FET on the fan low-side (V-) to 0V. I once used the LM317 approach and sensed an SMPS core at 50C and used a PN2222A  with a 10k thermistor and computed bias R's in a spreadsheet for min:max voltage in a common emitter for +/-5C full range. You may want <+/-1C which is almost a comparator which might be annoying hunting on/off from latency and mismatched anticipation.
But you will just be modulating 100W+/-5W, so for your 1st test, just run at full power with thermal protection.
If in doubt, you can always immerse the heatsink in water until you get comfortable with your power limiting & thermal limiter/cooling circuit.
Does that suit your expectations? Or do you want more details such as; measure T, Rsa, recompute Qh, heatsink design, AI fluid dynamics modelling etc?
Oh and don't forget Peltier clips.
https://www.sameskydevices.com/catalog/thermal-management/thermal-accessories/heat-sink-clips
