How to size heatsink for this thermoelectric heating application
As a part of experiment I also want the one side of this TEC(Peltier module) to be held at 50°C(where the room temperature is 25°C) and need to size a heatsink this time for the cold side.
The hot side to be monitored includes only a taped small wire element along with a thermistor for feedback to a TEC controller, and nothing else. And in this case, the heatsink will act as a heat reservoir. But as far as I understand, this time to the cold side I have to attach a heatsink otherwise the cold side will struggle. (For temperature regulation, I can use TEC controller which can both regulate for heating and cooling application.)
Here, its about to add heat to the system rather than remove heat. In cooling, we add Qc and electrical power to find total heat. But its a bit confusing in this case.
So in this case, what should be the way of thinking in steps to come up with a reasonable heatsink for the cold side? An example using the charts of the TEC would be great.

What is your Qh? If it is just the bare hot face of the TEC then I doubt you'll need anything unless you want to prevent condensation on the cold face.

Running water at 50 °C over the part you want to keep at 50 °C should work well.

it is just the bare hot face of the TEC

If you want to heat the hot side to 50 C, then you need do nothing with the cold side, except perhaps seal it from condensation. As heat is removed from the cold side, its temperature will drop, the ΔT increases, and at high enough ΔT, Qc will drop to zero. At this point, as much heat is getting to the cold face by conduction through the TEC from its internal resistive heating as is being pumped away by Peltier action. Basically, the TEC has become an expensive, fragile, resistive heater.
If you do add some heat to the cold side, this will appear at the hot side in addition to the resistive heating.

I see it makes very sense now. One more question whats the matter with condensation?  What could happen without heatsink on cold side I mean if we dont prevent condensation on the cold face O TEC. What is negative about condensation in this context?

It's bad because water and electronics usually don't mix. Yours doesn't appear to be sealed so condensation could work its way into the module and cause corrosion or other problems. If the condensation freezes then your Qc could drop since the ice will insulate the cold face.

Neil_UK says in heating mode the ΔT will start to increase and at high enough ΔT Qc eventually will got to zero. Its I think because the TEC controller will supply such current and at that current and ΔT the Oc will be zero. Only heating contribution will be from current and internal resistance of the Peltier. So if not sealed are you saying some moisture or water can get into the Peltier module? Lets say I prevent condensation but use no heatsink, would effect the 50 C regulation?

Can we say that these charts here https://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf useless in case of using it as heater?

@user16307 if you are already using it as a cooler, and sometimes want to heat, then it's excellent as a heater. It's at least 100% efficient, slightly more so if you allow heat into the cold side where it will add a little to the output. If you only ever want to heat, then you are far better off with a resistor, alli-clad bolt-down ones are ideal for heating surfaces.

@Neil_UK My problem is in heater mode lets say if I want to keep the TEC surface(only thermistor and a wire taped on hot side so almost no load) at 50 C by a TEC controller, I cannot show a rough math if a heatsink is required on the cold side to prevent condensation. Things make more sense with your help but I still cannot put these in formulas. So as far as I understand, you say Qc will be almost zero due to large delta T, and all the heating mechanism will come from TEC controller's current. Can we roughly estimate the power required( from TEC controller) to keep the bare TEC surface at 50C

I might have found it. Is that correct(to keep TEC side at 50 C)?: So at 5O C the hot side graph I look at the point where Qc=0 and ΔT=25(room temp). This is like 1.2A? Then from the other chart ΔT=25 and current=1.2A then V = 5V? And electrical power P = 6W . Does this make sense?

@user16307 If Tc is at room temp, then Th=50 implies dT=25. On the Th=50 chart, Q=0 dT=25 look to me to be about 1A. Don't cross to the Th=25 chart, because you've just told me that Th=50. Now if you keep the cold side at room temp by driving the TEC at only 1A, Qc will stay around 0. If you drive the TEC with more current, Qc will drop below room temp, and depending on the heatsink will absorb a little or a lot of heat Q from ambient.

Thanks a lot for replies. I only look at 50 C plot. I said 1.2A because thats how I interpolated by eye . How should I find the point at those lines. Did u draw a parallel by hand to come up with 1A? Im just curious. And secondly, if I use a TEC controller with thermistor feedback from 50C surface, and the cold side is not heatsinked in room temperature, the TEC controller will only provide 1A correct? I dont think it will source more current? Im asking if so, I dont need a heatsink to prevent condensation in such case? (im asking about at steady state)

@user16307 I didn't measure from the graph, hence only gave a round number. 1 is much the same as 1.2, as they are close, and both between 0 and 1.5. If the controller controls Th to 50 C, then it will only supply enough current to do that. If the load on the 50 C side is drawing a lot of heat, the controller will provide a lot of current, and Tc will drop. If the hot side is insulated, Qh = 0, the controller will provide zero current, and Tc will rise to 50 C. The cold side will end up at some temperature determined by the demand of the hot side for heat, and the characteristics of the TEC.

I see I should find the voltage for 1A for ΔT=25 from the other chart correct(its around 4V)? Instead of using the resistance of Peltier given in datasheet? I used IV instead of I^2R, thought R is not constant.
